# Pulling multiple emails from data table & making separate emails based on the same template

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to pull email addresses from a column in an Excel Data table and have those email addresses be the receiver of email based on a template.

Code I made below.

```
Sub Mail_experiment()
   Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
   Dim OutMail As Outlook.Mailtem
   Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   Set = OutMail
OutApp.CreatItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\Name\Documents\Project\PO Accrual Support Email Template.oft")
On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
   .To = "J.Doe@gmail.com"
   .CC = ""
   .BC = ""
   .Subject = ""
   .Save


End With
On Error GoTo 0
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

All separate emails will be sent later, hence `.Save`. Also, I am attempting to pull what would be the subject line of the email from another column in the data table.

How would I achieve both concepts with what I have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a function that returns a new `MailItem` based on your template.  In this way, you will be able to test the new `MailItem` separately without having to run the complete code.

I like to enumerate my excel columns.  This makes it both easier to refer to the correct column and to update the code if the column order is changed.

```
Option Explicit
'Enumeration is by defination the action of establishing the number of something
'I Enumerate my Worksheet Columns to give them a meaningful name that is easy to recognize
Public Enum EmailColumns
    ecEmailAdresses = 1
    ecSubject = 3
End Enum

Public Sub SaveEmails()
    Dim r As Long
    'The With Statement allows you to "perform a series of statements on a specified object without specifying the name of the object multiple times"
    '.Cells(.Rows.Count, ecEmailAdresses).End(xlUp).Row actually refers to ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Support Emails").Cells(.Rows.Count, ecEmailAdresses).End(xlUp).Row
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Support Emails")
        '.Cells(): references a cell or range of cells on Worksheets("Support Emails")
        '.Cells(.Rows.Count, ecEmailAdresses): Refrences the last cell in column 1 of the worksheet
        '.End(xlUp): Changes the refererence from the last cell to the first used cell above the last cell in column 3
        '.Cells(.Rows.Count, ecEmailAdresses).End(xlUp).Row: returns the Row number of the last used cell in column 3
        For r = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, ecEmailAdresses).End(xlUp).Row
            getPOAccrualTemplate(MailTo:=.Cells(r, ecEmailAdresses), Subject:=.Cells(r, ecEmailAdresses)).Save
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Public Function getPOAccrualTemplate(MailTo As String, Optional CC As String, Optional BCC As String, Optional Subject As String) As Object
    Const TEMPLATE_PATH As String = "C:\Users\Name\Documents\Project\PO Accrual Support Email Template.oft"
    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
    ' CreateObject("Outlook.Application"): Creates an instance of an Outlook Application.
    ' Outlook.Application.CreateItemFromTemplate returns a new MailItem Based on a saved email template
    Set OutMail = CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItemFromTemplate(TEMPLATE_PATH)

    With OutMail
        .To = MailTo
        .CC = CC
        .BCC = BCC
        .Subject = Subject
    End With
    'Returns the new MailItem to the caller of the function
    Set getPOAccrualTemplate = OutMail

End Function
```

### Immediate Window Tests

```
'Test getPOAccrualTemplate
' Assign Values to Varaible
MailTo   = "ti@stackoverflow.com"
CC       = "efrenreyes@youdontwantnoneson.com"
BCC      = "alexp@gmail.com"
Subject  = "Who is going to the tournament tonight?"
'Test Variables using "," to insert Tabs between values
?MailTo, CC, BCC, Subject
?MailTo;"-";CC;"-";BCC;"-";Subject
'Pass variables into getPOAccrualTemplate and return a new MailItem based on the template
'variables created in the immediate window are Variant Type
'CStr is used to cast the values to Strings
set OutMail = getPOAccrualTemplate(CStr(MailTo), CStr(CC), CStr(BCC), CStr(Subject))
'Find out what type of object was returned 
?TypeName(OutMail)
'Display the Mail Item
OutMail.Display
'Test Enumerate Columns
Columns(EmailColumns.ecEmailAdresses).Select
Columns(ecSubject).Select
MailTo   = Cells(2, ecEmailAdresses)
CC       = ""
BCC      = ""
Subject  = Cells(2, ecSubject)
'Test the function directly
getPOAccrualTemplate(CStr(MailTo), CStr(CC), CStr(BCC), CStr(Subject)).Display
'Test SaveEmails() Make sure and add a breakpoint 
SaveEmails
?.Cells(.Rows.Count, ecEmailAdresses).End(xlUp).Row
```

[image: Immediate Window Demo]

### Video Tutorials

These are two videos from my favorite VBA tutorial series that are relevant:

- [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)
- [Excel VBA Introduction Part 26 - Constants and Enumerations (Const, Enum)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=d8cfrdUjcuw&index=29&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Comment: what is the sections [ecEmailAdressess = 1] and [ecSubject = 3] achieving?

Comment: You should read [MSDN Enum Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/enum-statement).  An enumeration is a way of grouping const integer values.  In the above example `ecEmailAdressess ` would be used to refer to column 1.  `Cells(r, ecEmailAdressess )` is more descriptive then `Cells(r, 1)` or  `Cells(r, "A")` but all three examples are equivalent.

Comment: Oh ok. Will it adapt when more data is added to the table?

Comment: The code loops from 2 to the last used cells in column `ecEmailAdressess `.

Comment: Where should I put this code? The sheet with the table or a module?

Comment: I prefer using `Public Modules` over worksheet modules but it will work from either one.

Comment: I am receiving a runtime error at [code](getPOAccrualTemplate(MailTo:=.Cells(r, ecEmailAdresses), Subject:=.Cells(r, ecEmailAdresses)).Save). Is it running for you?

Comment: I tested and updated my answer.  I used two typos from your code to write my answer `CreatItemFromTemplate` and `.BC`.

Comment: Do you think you could add comments to the code to help me understand what each line does? Just in case I or someone else would need to edit it. Thank you.

Comment: Wow! Thank you @TinMan! This helps me a lot.

Comment: @FinanceGuy :) Happy coding!

Comment: what is the section `Set getPOAccrualTemplate = OutMail` doing?

Comment: `OutMail` is the newly created mail item.  `Set getPOAccrualTemplate = OutMail` is returning the `OutMail` object as the value of the `getPOAccrualTemplate ` function.

Comment: So it's not necessarily sending it to Drafts when I run the macro. Do the emails just go to Drafts because when you create an email and don't send it Outlook defaults the email to Drafts?

Comment: I am trying to understand it for I want to send the emails to a specific draft folder but I am having a hard time understanding the process. \

Answer (score 0):

You should just slightly refactor your code. The macro sending the email should take (at least) the email adress and the subject in parameter:

```
Sub Mail_experiment(ByVal address As String, ByVal subject As String)
   Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
   Dim OutMail As Outlook.Mailtem
   Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   Set = OutMail
   OutApp.CreatItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\Name\Documents\Project\PO Accrual Support Email Template.oft")
   On Error Resume Next
   With OutMail
   .To = address '<-- use the input here
   .CC = ""
   .BC = ""
   .Subject = subject '<-- use the input here
   .Save
   End With
   On Error GoTo 0
   Set OutMail = Nothing
   Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Hence, supposing you have the email addresses in the column A and the subjects in the column B (from 1 to 10, for example), you'd just need to call the macro in a loop:

```
For j = 1 To 10
    Mail_experiment Range("A" & j), Range("B" & j)
Next j
```

The above will call the `Mail_experiment` macro 10 times, each time passing a new parameter (A1 - B1, then A2 - B2 etc.)

Comment: Will it create multiple separate emails?

Comment: Also where would I implement that loop because I keep getting "Compile error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"?

Comment: you'll need to clean up and merge the line below `Set = OutMail`

Comment: What do you mean "clean up and merge"? I'm new to VBA so if you could explain in more detail that would be great.